# Beaglebone problems flashing from eMMC card to on board eMMC

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I have a typical two partition Image running from a sd card on the beaglebone. I have tried to copy it to the onboard flash with no success. I have tried the flasher v3 & v2 plus the one given by https://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents. I also tried using the command dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/mmcblk1 but that didn't work because I had not formatted the On Board Flash eMMCblk1. The Image was originally on a Beaglebone Green I saved it using https://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents, but then was not able to write it back to a green board or black, right after I made it without having made any changes. So I wrote it to a flash card and have been booting from the flash drive. I have made changes to the programming and would like to make a flasher out of the card to use with any Beaglebone. Any help would be great. The Debian image date is 2015-07-13. It is running Mysql, Python, and php files all married together. Is there a way I can just format the on board flash and just copy the Partitions down to it? It currently boots and runs fine on a BBG or BBB. When I run the v3 flasher from the command line on the BBG this is the result. sudo ./init-eMMC-flasher-v3-bbg.sh

### Starting eMMC Flasher

```
Checking for Valid BBG EEPROM header
Invalid EEPROM header detected
Writing header to EEPROM
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
16 bytes (16 B) copied, 0.00456354 s, 3.5 kB/s
eeprom check: [A335BNLTBB]
```

All Boards I have worked with are the C Version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is documentation on this somewhere or not, however; what I have discovered is that for the newer production beaglebone boards, something is different about them and I really am not sure what that is. With that being said the only Wheezy Image that will flash a new board is the 7.11 Image dated 2016-06-15. Once I started using that Image Flashing was not a problem. So if you still require Wheezy you can only use this Image, no other posted Image will flash the boards. I think that this Image must have been released just for this purpose as it was the last Wheezy Image to be released even though it has a lower version number of 7.11. Other wheezy versions go up to 7.9 but they have an older release date and they will not flash a newer board.